# regex cant be equal to 0

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will accept an input as long as it doesn't equal 0. To clarify, I mean only 0. An input that contains a 0 would still match, for instance 408.

This is what I have so far:

```
^[^0]
```

Comment: what do you mean by `equal 0`? numerically or string literally?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr this is regex, the input will obviously be text.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of text that **should** match and text that should **not** match?

Comment: @Gusdor it has nothing to do with regex. if op wants string literal comparison, it should be no more than `input!="0"` or `!input.equals("0")` depending on the language.

Comment: Is `01` valid or not?

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE "An input that contains a 0 would still match, for instance 408."

Comment: @KendallFrey: I guess you're right, so I give you my point, but that isn't so clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
^(?!0$).*
```

Essentially, it checks that the start of the string is not followed by a `0` and the end of the string. The only string that this is the case is `"0"`, so all others will be matched.

However, if you're controlling the validation yourself, it would be easier to just forgo regex and check that the string is not equal to `"0"`.

Answer (score 1):

see this demo https://regex101.com/r/vS6vT3/1

```
/^[^0]{1}.*$/gm
```

or with Negative Lookahead

```
/^(?!0{1}$).*$/gm
```

Comment: What is it about this pattern that makes the regex work? Why is `{1}` required? This does not match `0abc` but i have a feeling that it should

Comment: This will also not match the empty string, and nothing in the question indicates that it should not match the empty string.